# The most proper way to isolate statefull beans during concurrent exchanges

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, apache-camel

Let's say there is a route from which a statefull bean is invoked:

```
<camel:route id="Concurrently-called-route">
    <camel:from uri="direct:concurrentlyCalledRoute"/>
    <camel:bean ref="statefullBean" method="setSomeState"/>
    <camel:bean ref="statefullBean" method="getSomeDataDependingOnState"/>
</camel:route>
```

Messages could be sent along this route concurrently, i.e. `requestBody` method of `ProducerTemplate` is called from concurrent threads. So a problem would arise if two excahnges were going and `setSomeState` was called during one exchange in between of calls to `setSomeState` and `getSomeDataDependingOnState` performed during another exchange. I see two ways to solve this problem each of which has a drawback.

**Using SEDA**

```
<camel:route id="Councurrently-called-route">
    <camel:from uri="direct:concurrentlyCalledRoute"/>
    <camel:to uri="seda:sedaRoute"/>
</camel:route>

<camel:route id="SEDA-route">
    <camel:from uri="seda:sedaRoute"/>
    <camel:bean ref="statefullBean" method="setSomeState"/>
    <camel:bean ref="statefullBean" method="getSomeDataDependingOnState"/>
</camel:route>
```

In this case messages sent from different threads gather in a queue of the SEDA endpoint. Messages from this queue is handled in one thread while going along `SEDA-route`. So processing of a message won't interfere processing of another one. However, if there were many threads sending messages to `concurrentlyCalledRoute` `SEDA-route` would be a bottleneck. If more than one thread were used to handle items from the seda queue the problem with concurrent calls to statefull beans would arise again.

Another way - use custom scope.

**Custom scope**

Spring Framework allows to implement custom scopes. So we are able to implement a scope which will store a separate instance of a bean for each excahange.

```
public class ExchangeScope implements Scope {

    private Map<String, Map<String,Object>> instances = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private Map<String,Runnable> destructionCallbacks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private final ThreadLocal<String> currentExchangeId = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public void activate(String exchangeId) {
        if (!this.instances.containsKey(exchangeId)) {
            Map<String, Object> instancesInCurrentExchangeScope = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            this.instances.put(exchangeId, instancesInCurrentExchangeScope);
        }
        this.currentExchangeId.set(exchangeId);
    }

    public void destroy() {
        String currentExchangeId = this.currentExchangeId.get();
        Map<String,Object> instancesInCurrentExchangeScope = instances.get(currentExchangeId);
        if (instancesInCurrentExchangeScope == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("ExchangeScope with id = " + currentExchangeId + " doesn't exist");
        for (String name : instancesInCurrentExchangeScope.keySet()) {
            this.remove(name);
        }
        instances.remove(currentExchangeId);
        this.currentExchangeId.set(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(String name, ObjectFactory<?> objectFactory) {
    // selects by name a bean instance from a map storing instances for current exchange
    // creates a new bean instance if necessary
    }

    @Override
    public Object remove(String name) {
    // removes a bean instance
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDestructionCallback(String name, Runnable callback) {
        this.destructionCallbacks.put(name, callback);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveContextualObject(String name) {
        String currentExchangeId = this.currentExchangeId.get();
        if (currentExchangeId == null)
            return null;

        Map<String,Object> instancesInCurrentExchangeScope = this.instances.get(currentExchangeId);
        if (instancesInCurrentExchangeScope == null)
            return null;

        return instancesInCurrentExchangeScope.get(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String getConversationId() {
        return this.currentExchangeId.get();
    }
}
```

Now we can register this custom scope and declare `statefullBean` as exchange scoped:

```
<bean id="exchangeScope" class="org.my.ExchangeScope"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
    <property name="scopes">
        <map>
            <entry key="ExchangeScope" value-ref="exchangeScope"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="statefullBean" class="org.my.StatefullBean" scope="ExchangeScope"/>
```

To use exchange scope we should call `activate` method of `ExchangeScope` before sending a message and call `destroy` after that:

```
this.exchangeScope.activate(exchangeId);
this.producerTemplate.requestBody(request);
this.exchangeScope.destroy(exchangeId);
```

With this implementation a exchange scope is actually a thread scope. And this is a drawback. If for example multithreaded splitter was used in a route it would be unable to call exchange scoped beans from threads created by the splitter because calls to beans would be performed in threads different from a thread an exchange is started in.

Any ideas how to work around these drawbacks? Are there completelly different ways to isolate statefull beans during concurrent exchanges?

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to consider is to not make your beans stateful. You can store the state data in the message itself rather than in the bean, so your methods would look something like:

```
public class StatefulBean {
    public StateInfo setSomeState(Message msg) {...}

    public void getSomeDataDependingOnState(StateInfo stateinfo) {...}
}
```

Comment: +1 - I agree, trying to work around the problem is more complex than reworking/wrapping your stateful beans...the Exchange should contain thread scoped information...anything referenced external to the Exchange should be thread safe by design...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `seda` queue, it's designed for exactly this sort of problem.

Given that you can process the messages faster than they come in, this should be ideal. A general ballpark for the size limit of the seda queue would be around 10,000 - obviously you can tune it according to your needs.

I was faced with a similar situation in my project where I receive an initial block of around 2000 messages, and then 1 message per second thereafter. They are required to be processed in a specified order, so I put the messages onto a seda queue for sequential processing and it can take 3-5 seconds to clear them all.

Otherwise you could find a way to use a difference instance of your bean, per exchange...